# Strange Request for semi-colon

Tags: sql

I am trying to make an update to a table creation statement but run into the following error: 
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 15
Incorrect syntax near ';'.

Any pointers would be appreciated.

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM .information_schema.tables WHERE table_name = 'DeviceDashboard')
BEGIN
    DROP TABLE dbo.DeviceDashboard
END

SELECT * INTO DeviceDashboard
FROM
(
select
b.*, sm.sector
from RPT_DeviceDashboard b
left outer join  sectormapping sm
on b.industry = sm.industry
);
```

Comment: Steve Kass told you the reason for your error.  The error message suggests that you are using sql server.  In that case, a table variable or temporary table might be a better approach than your current one.

Answer (score 4):

You probably have to provide a table alias for the subselect.

```
...
  on b.industry = sm.industry
) AS T;
```

Comment: That does it. Thanks.